# Key "enable-interactive-search" not found

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 14.10, glib

Nautilus doesn't open. Here is terminal output:

```
** (nautilus:7905): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist

** (nautilus:7905): WARNING **: Can't load fallback CSS resource: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-fallback.css' does not exist

(nautilus:7905): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' does not contain a key named 'enable-interactive-search'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

As you see in the third line, nautilus couldn't find key `enable-interactive-search` in the schema `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences`.

What I've already done with no luck:

- Manually editing of `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml` and then running `dconf update`
- Trying to set that key with `gsettings set` but it saied `no such key`
- Reinstalling my nautilus `apt-get install --reinstall nautilus`
- Resinstalling my `glib2.0` by Synaptics package manager

More Info:

- Ubuntu **14.10**
- Nautilus **3.10.1**
- libglib2.0 **2.42.1**
- `gedit` also won't open, gives a similar error indicating key `enable-delete` doesn't exist in that schema.

Comment: 'dpkg -S /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml' shows that it is from nautilus-data package. Maybe walk around with 'apt-cache depends <package>' command and check other packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and just reinstalling gedit worked to fix it

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit
```